# AWS AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient cannot read credentials in .NET Framework application

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store, aws-credentials

I have .NET Framework application where I try to read data from AWS parameter store using `AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient` on my local environment. Besides I have credentials generated by AWS CLI and located in

*Users/MyUser/.aws*

folder. When I try to connect to the parameter store from CMD using the creds it works fine. Though the AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient in the application with default constructor, it throws exception "*Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.*" When I tried to pass BasicAWSParameters to the client with hardcoded working keys I got another exception "*The security token included in the request is invalid*".

Also I tried installing EC2Config, initializing AWS SDK Store from Visual Studio AWS Toolkit. Though it didn't change the game.
I would want to avoid using environment variables or hardcoding the keys since keys are generated and valid only 1 hour. Then I should regenerate so copying them somewhere every time is not convenient for me.
Please advice how to resolve the issue.

Some code

```
_client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient()
public string GetValue(string key)
{
    if (_client == null)
        return null;

    var request = new GetParameterRequest
    {
        Name = $"{_baseParameterPath}/{key}",
        WithDecryption = true,
    };

    try
    {
        var response = _client.GetParameterAsync(request).Result;

        return response.Parameter.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

credentials file looks as following (I removed key values not to expose):

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id= KEY VALUE
aws_secret_access_key= KEY VALUE
aws_session_token= KEY VALUE

[MyProfile]
aws_access_key_id= KEY VALUE
aws_secret_access_key= KEY VALUE
aws_session_token= KEY VALUE
```

Comment: please show how you are configuring your client

Comment: @DanielA.White, added code to the post

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have your creds in .aws/credentials, you can create the Service client and the creds will be located and used.  No need to create a BasicAWSParameters object.

Creds in a file named credentials:

[image]

[default]

aws_access_key_id=Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aws_secret_access_key=/zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

This .NET code works.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement;
using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model;

  namespace ConsoleApp1 { 
    class Program {

    static async Task Main(string[] args) {

  
      var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient();
      var request = new GetParameterRequest()
      {
           Name = "RDSConnection"
      };

      var response = client.GetParameterAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
      Console.WriteLine("Parameter value is " + response.Parameter.Value);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is what I tried to do but it does not work. Throws exception "Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service."

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible. It works fine on my end.

Comment: If it would work fine for me, I wouldn't ask any questions

Comment: how did you create your creds ?

Comment: The Creds are IAM User creds that is then placed in the .AWS folder in a file named credentials. See update on my response